# Realizar calculos direto na consulta sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Como poderia realizar uma serie de cálculos direto na consulta sql, como existe o `SUM()` que realiza a soma teria alguma forma de Somar uma coluna a outra e diminuir outra?

```
$sql02 = mysql_query("SELECT * , SUM(valor) as tt FROM finan  "); 
$dados02 = mysql_fetch_array($sql02); 

$fev_c  = $dados02[$pg];
$fev_v  = $dados02[$pg];
$tot =  $dados02['tt'];
$juros  = $dados02['multa'];
$multa  = $dados02['juros'];
$desconto  = $dados02['desconto'];

// abaixo é o calculo que atualmente fasso é e isso que queria fazer direto na consulta
$fev2 = $tot+$juros+$multa-$desconto;
```

minha pergunta é teria como esse calculo ja ser feito na consulta

```
SELECT *, SUM(valor) as tt FROM finan;
```

Comment: Pode, sem problema nenhum. Qual foi a dificuldade encontrada?

Comment: exemplo SUM(valor) as tt  + SUM(juros) as jj + SUM(multa) as ss - SUM(desconto) as dd    como sairia isso

Comment: É uma expressão só, então é um AS só. SUM(valor) + SUM( ..... AS total.

Comment: Show funcionou aqui... não sabia que podia fazer isso SUM(valor) + SUM( ..... valeu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não tem problema nenhum fazer as operações no SQL

```
SELECT
   SUM(valor)    AS totalvalor,
   SUM(juros)    AS totaljuros,
   SUM(multa)    AS totalmulta,
   SUM(desconto) AS totaldesconto,
   SUM(valor + juros + multa - desconto) AS totalgeral
FROM
   financeiro
```

O importante é que você tenha um *alias* para cada expressão para facilitar o uso na linguagem-cliente.

Mais que isso: em outros cenários você pode fazer operações condicionais e efetivamente "criar" novas colunas no retorno com base nisto:

```
SELECT
   SUM(IF(operacao='d',valor,0)) AS debito,
   SUM(IF(operacao='c',valor,0)) AS credito
FROM
   tabela
```

Novamente, vale a idéia de um *alias* para cada expressão.

Conforme observado pelo colega [@Motta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5005/), se houver qualquer valor nulo nos campos, o resultado total é anulado. Se este for o seu caso, pode zerar os valores nulos desta forma:

Em vez de usar:

```
SUM( coluna1 + coluna2 ...
```

Dê preferência a:

```
SUM( COALESCE( coluna1, 0 ) + COALESCE( coluna2, 0 ) ...
```

O `COALESCE` faz uma cascata de valores na lista de parâmetros, até que estes acabem ou um não nulo seja encontrado. No nosso caso, como só usamos dois, é retornado o primeiro, a não ser que este seja nulo, quando será retornado o `0` em seu lugar.

Comment: Perfeito.......

Comment: Desta forma apenas cuidado com valores nulos , um valor nulo numa linha , "desconto" por exemplo anularia toda o SUM(valor + juros + multa - desconto) AS totalgeral mas não os SUM(valor)    AS totalvalor,
   SUM(juros)    AS totaljuros,
   SUM(multa)    AS totalmulta, anularia também o    SUM(desconto) AS totaldesconto,

Comment: @Motta acrescentada observação na resposta e solução. Grato pela observação.